# Repairing from Live USB

Tags: linux, linux-mint, boot, live-usb

I need to repair a network related package (Samba) that is preventing my system from booting. (mint 17).

I have a bootable USB stick with the same OS. How would I fix the broken package on my hard disk through the USB operating system?

Comment: Give me a few minutes, and I'll have an answer for you....  This takes awhile as I have to create a `chroot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the package(s) that you need and use `dkpg` with the `--instdir` option:

```
dpkg --instdir=/path/to/mounted/HDD --install yourpackage.deb
```

you might want to use `--purge` (also with the appropriate `--instdir`!!) first if `dpkg` doesn't want to overwrite a half installed package.

Answer (score 0):

### Fix

The easiest way to do this is to create a chroot, and then perform the repair operations inside the chroot.  You do this by:

1. Verify the network works outside the chroot.  Issue a `sudo ifconfig`.
2. Create a mountpoint for your installation that needs fixing.  Issue a `sudo mkdir -pv /mnt/mymint`
3. Now mount your installation.  Issue `sudo mount -v -t ext4 /dev/sdX` where X is the letter for your root partition.  You may need to change the `-t` option depending on your filesystem.
4. Verify your swap partition.  Issue `sudo swapon /dev/sdY` where Y is your swap partition.
5. Issue the following commands to sync up the LiveDisk with your install:
   `mount -t proc proc /mnt/mymint/proc`
   `mount --rbind /sys /mnt/mymint/sys`
   `mount --rbind /dev /mnt/mymint/dev`
6. Enter Your Change Root.  Issue:
   `chroot /mnt/mymint /bin/bash`
   `source /etc/profile`
   `export PS1="(chroot) $PS1"`
7. Now we don't have to use any extra options with any Targets as in Anthon's Answer.  We can use apt-get(Do this for all Broken packages):
   `sudo apt-get remove --purge brokenpackagename && sudo apt-get-install packagename`
8. Reboot.  Issue:
   `exit`
   `umount -l /mnt/mymint/dev{/shm,/pts,}`
   `umount /mnt/mymint{/boot,/sys,/proc,}`
   `reboot`

---

### Reasoning

My personal opinion is that using a changeroot is the safest approach because, in this way nothing from the LiveCD/USB interferes with your system.  I'll admit this approach probably scares off some newer users, but I can assure you that this work as it is the method that the Gentoo Distribution uses for new installs.  If interested, see [Chapter 6 of the Gentoo Install Handbook](https://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?part=1&chap=6).